# remove last folder from path in nodejs with trailing and no trailng /

Tags: javascript, node.js

Suppose I have a path

```
C:/Oracle/ or C:/Oracle
```

How can I remove the last folder and get the result as

```
c:/
```

Comment: Using regex: `path.match(/(.*\/)[^/]+\/?/)?.[1]`

Comment: Since this is a Windows path, it has to be `C:\Oracle\` or `C:\Oracle`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To work with path, there is the default [`path` module](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html)

```
const path = require('path')
console.log(path.join('c:/Oracle', '../'))
```

Comment: And you should always use the path module to avoid operation system compatibility issues!

Comment: or `path.resolve()`? I never know the differences between `join`, `resolve`, `normalize` etc. because they all seem to do the same thing and eventually give you the URL you want

Comment: I linked the docs, the differences are deepening there

Answer (score 0):

```
    inputFilePath = "C:/Oracle/sub1/sub2"

    var parts = inputFilePath.split(new RegExp("\/"));

    parts.forEach(function(part, index, array) {

        var sub = part + "/"
        console.log("Foldernames: " + sub);
    });
```

Output:

Foldernames: C:/
Foldernames: Oracle/
Foldernames: sub1/
Foldernames: sub2/